# Find max of a specific column but return another column in pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have 3 columns mainly country, type (type of investment) and amount. I would like to know the country which has the maximum amount invested per investment type. So the expected list of countries are "can, gb, ind".

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    df = pd.DataFrame({"country": ["ind", "usa", "gb", "ind", "gb", "usa", "can", "can", "usa", "ind", "gb", "can"], \
    "type":["deposit", "bonds", "cash", "cash", "bonds", "deposit", "bonds", "deposit", "deposit", "bonds", "cash", "deposit"], \
    "amount": [1000, 120, 90, 200, 150, 300, 100, 400, 250, 300, 250, 5000]})

    print(df)
    print(df.groupby("type")["amount"].max())
    ##How to get the corresponding coutry per max amount of the investment type?

    amount country     type
0     1000     ind  deposit
1      120     usa    bonds
2       90      gb     cash
3      200     ind     cash
4      150      gb    bonds
5      300     usa  deposit
6      100     can    bonds
7      400     can  deposit
8      250     usa  deposit
9      300     ind    bonds
10     250      gb     cash
11    5000     can  deposit
type
bonds       300
cash        250
deposit    5000
Name: amount, dtype: int64
```

I am able to group it by the type of investment and compute the max, but how to extract the corresponding country name?

Comment: use `df.groupby(['country','type'])['amount'].max()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can using `drop_duplicates`

```
df.sort_values(['type','amount']).drop_duplicates('type',keep='last')
Out[285]: 
    amount country     type
9      300     ind    bonds
10     250      gb     cash
11    5000     can  deposit
```

Or just using `idxmax`

```
df.loc[df.groupby('type')['amount'].idxmax()]
Out[287]: 
    amount country     type
9      300     ind    bonds
10     250      gb     cash
11    5000     can  deposit
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `country` and `type` in your `groupby` clause.

```
df.groupby(['country','type'])['amount'].max().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
    country type    amount
0   can    bonds    100
1   can    deposit  5000
2   gb     bonds    150
3   gb     cash     250
4   ind    bonds    300
5   ind    cash     200
6   ind    deposit  1000
7   usa    bonds    120
8   usa    deposit  300
```